# run perl script on file I'm editing with vim (macvim)

Tags: vim

I have been using bluefish to edit text that are to be published in html. Bluefish has an external filter function that allows me to call on scripts that I have written in perl to "filter" the text I am editing and format them basically using regex.

Having started exploring vim and macvim, I find the program to be very powerful and worth learning. I just would like to be able to use those scripts I already have without having to rewrite them as vim plugins. I have spent the past 2 hours searching but answers seem to be only for running perl as an external command or incorporating perl inside vim scripts.

Just to be clear: I want to get perl scripts I already have to act on text that I am presently editing inside vim/macvim, either the whole text or (better) selected text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
:%!command
```

for example

```
:%!sort
```

to sort the whole file being edited.

If you have a range selected it will be added automatically and you complete the command

```
:'<,'>!command
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear (because I was confused), :%!/path/to/script works on whole text, :'<,'>!/path/to/script works on selection. I have been seeing :%!command and didn't think command can be a script...

Comment: For completeness, we call these external script "filters" and they are a core part of the "UNIX way". Vim's internal help will… help: `:h filter`.

Comment: Just a follow-up question: is there a way to set `filter1 = /path/to/script` so I don't have to type "/path/to/script" to run the script each time but just run ':%!filter1'?

Comment: @DaneBoi, this is a full fledged question which requires a serious answer. Please consider asking a new question.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335268/shortcuts-to-scripts-while-using-vim)