# Shortcuts to scripts while using Vim

Tags: vim

I just learned that I can run perl scripts on my vim text window by using
    :%!/path/to/script
Is there a way to `set filter1 = /path/to/script` so I only need to type `:%!filter1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cabbrev` to create a command-line abbreviation like this:

```
:cabbrev filter1 /path/to/script
```

If you the type `filter1` followed by a space it will expand to to `/path/to/script`.
And you can also put the `%!` into the abbreviation if you only use it in this combination.

Obviously, if you use this filter a lot it might be easier to create a keybinding for this:

```
map ,f :%!/path/to/script<cr>
```

This will map `,f` to executing your filter...

Comment: Added "cabbrev filter1 /path/to/script" to .vimrc for a more permanent solution. Thanks f3lix.

Comment: [You should not be using neither `cabbrev`, nor `map`.](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) For the first there is `cnoreabbrev`. For the second there is `nnoremap` (note the leading `n`: you don’t need this mapping in visual or operator-pending mode, in first case it just even won’t work at all).

Comment: Thanks, ZyX. Will be sure to use those "nore" versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can also place your script somewhere in your `$PATH`.

The `scriptname` command is now available to vim (and other programs) for use on the command line.

```
:!scriptname<CR>
```

Obviously, if you use that command often, you should create a mapping in your `~/.vimrc`.

***edit***

On Mac OS X, all terminal emulators use a login shell by default. It means that, for day-to-day terminal usage, the right place for defining aliases, altering your `$PATH`, setting shell variables or exporting environment variables is actually `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile`. In this context, `~/.bashrc` is totally useless.

But MacVim doesn't use a login shell by default. Actually, it doesn't even use an interactive shell. The immediate consequence is that, by default, MacVim is able to see environment variables (`export FOO='bar'`) but it can't see our aliases (`alias foo='bar'`) or shell variables (`BAZ='foo'`), whether they are set in `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Thankfully, we only need to change an option in Vim to make it use an interactive shell and thus see the aliases defined in `~/.bashrc`:

```
:set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

But we end up with two configuration files: `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`. Aliases defined in the first are available in all terminal sessions but not in Vim and those defined in the second are available in Vim but invisible in a regular terminal session.

One solution could be to add the `-l` flag to the option above to make MacVim run an interactive login shell (and thus make use of what we have in our `~/.profile`).

Another solution would be to `source ~/.profile` in `~/.bashrc` as I did a couple of years ago.

But, as @ZyX correctly suggested in his comment, the whole thing could become messy and probably have performance issues.

In my opinion, the best course of action, on Mac OS X, is thus probably to leave `shellcmdflag` at its default value, put whatever aliases/variables/functions you need in your day-to-day terminal usage in `~/.profile` (not `~/.bashrc` as it is not executed by default) and simply place your custom scripts in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Wow, you guys rock! (And so does Vim). Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately a few limitations:  `:cabbrev` works as advertised but Vim doesn't remember the abbreviation. Goes away once I close macvim or even in a new window. No I need this more permanently.  The alias trick doesn't quite work (Mountain lion, haven't tried under linux yet). Yes I have sourced .bashrc after that. I get a command not found message. Looks like the map thingy is my best bet. Not so good for selections though, I think. Maybe I should just place the scripts in $PATH. Thanks again.

Comment: Just want to add that I did try the above suggestions inside a terminal too.

Comment: Placing the script somewhere in your `$PATH` is sure to work. About `:cabbrev` not being remembered; custom commands, custom mappings, custom settings and whatnot are supposed to be added to a `~/.vimrc` file that you must create yourself. Generally, you only have to remove the `:`, `:nnoremap something something` becoming `nnoremap something something`.

Comment: Also, in reality it's a bit more complicated but, in general, `alias` and `PATH` belong to your `~/.profile`, not to your `~/.bashrc`. You can do `:echo $PATH` in Vim to see what `$PATH` it really sees.

Comment: Thanks @romainl. I put "cabbrev filter1 /path/to/script" inside my .vimrc and it works. That solves my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @romainl Aliases belong to `.bashrc`, never to `.profile`. Just test `echo $'alias v=vim'>>~/.profile<CR>\bash -i<CR>`. You won’t see your alias: new shell is not a login one. Neither you will when using `vim -u NONE` as invoking shell as a login or interactive shell is not a default setting, so forget about aliases for vim at all (forcing invocation as a login/interactive shell, especially the second, just adds mostly useless reading of the configuration and very significant performance impact, especially for complex configurations).

Comment: @ZyX, the OP's previous question was about MacVim which is known for doing funny things with environment variables. My answer took this particularity into consideration but your comment made me curious: I'll do some experiments tomorrow morning.

Comment: @ZyX, Mac OS X's terminal emulators typically use login shells (as crazy or non-standard as that might be) so `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`) is actually the right place for aliases or setting up your `$PATH` or whatever. I mixed things up, though. MacVim indeed doesn't get aliases declared in `~/.profile` and that's why I've had `source ~/.profile` for years in `~/.bashrc`. I stupidly inverted causality and forgot, in the process, my own findings of years ago.

Comment: @ZyX, I had a power outage at work while editing my answer. I'll try to find some times to rewrite it later today.

Comment: @romainl I never said that terminals are not using login shells (they may or may not do this, it is irrelevant) or that `~/.profile` is wrong place to define `$PATH`. It is wrong place to define *aliases* as they are not exported to new non-login shells. `$PATH` *is* exported though, but I still prefer to use `.zshrc` for this purpose though with code that checks for duplicates; mainly for historical reasons (i.e. I do this now because I already did it before, likely not knowing about `~/.zprofile`).

Comment: @romainl `.profile` was always the correct place for defining *only* exported variables: because if you need an interactive shell you use `-i` flag in scripts, not one for login. And interactivity is deduced by default by shell if you launch it with simple `zsh` without arguments and with tty stdin/stdout/stderr, login shell is almost never launched by default. `dtach`, `tmux` and `screen` are not launching a login shell and if you once want to add code to secure shells from accidental terminal emulator shutdown you need to have settings in `bashrc`/`zshrc` or explicit `--login` argument.

Comment: @ZyX, you are right of course. But in Mac OS X, new shells (as in "a new Terminal.app window") *always* start a new login shell. If you define aliases anywhere else than in `.profile` or `.bash_profile` you'll *never* be able to use them unless you somehow start a non-login interactive shell. If you don't explicitely do `bash -i`, `.bashrc` will never be executed. So no, aliases don't "belong to `.bashrc`, never to `.profile`" and adding an alias to `.profile` is what I initially suggested. I was wrong but not because "Aliases belong to `.bashrc`, never to `.profile`".

Comment: I was wrong because, in its default state, MacVim won't see any alias, whether they are in `.profile` or `.bashrc`. Either vim is tweaked to run a non-login interactive shell to see the aliases put in `.bashrc`, either it is tweaked to run a login shell to see what's set in `.profile` or it's not tweaked at all and we don't expect Vim to be able to use any alias at all.

Comment: @romainl Ah, did not know bash has that “fine” feature: interactive login shell does not source `.bashrc` (not a bug: `man bash` states this). For zsh it is much clearer: every interactive shell sources `.zshrc` unless explicitly forbidden by special arguments. Every login shell does so for `.zprofile` (unless forbidden). No exceptions for the case when shell is both login and interactive. Wondering what is the reason for bash behavior: in this case you will have to add `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.profile` or you will see configuration not working here or there.

Comment: @ZyX, that's right, I actually have `source ~/.profile` in `~/.bashrc`. Everything I read makes me want to switch to zsh…

Comment: I remember reading that there is a particular sequence that bash takes to read these files, including /etc/profile, ~/profile, bash_login, bash_profile. I also vaguely remember that a clean user home in osx does not have any of these files. I added .bash_profile whose sole purpose was to source .bashrc. Everything else goes into .bashrc because that was what I was used to in my linux boxes. Not intending to ignite further discussion but just to point out that there are many ways to configure. @romainl, thanks for pointing out the anomaly about MacVim.

Comment: @DaneBoi This sequence is described in man page. I just don’t use bash and can’t imagine such *weird* thing as interactive shell **not** sourcing bashrc by default. For zsh my words about `.zprofile` are true: it sources `.zshrc` always in case it is interactive thus splitting (exported variables to zprofile, everything else to zshrc) makes sense as environment is inherited.

Comment: @romainl I checked terminal emulators I use and it appears that xterm and rxvt-unicode start login interactive shell and konsole starts non-login interactive shell. Thus you will definitely need `source` on linux even if you don’t bother about the case when you manually launch shell.